# Which is faster and cleaner, generate AST and iterate on it or generate code?

Tags: javascript, parsing, code-generation, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I wrote an interpreter in JavaScript for a small language using [jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/), which is a JS port of bison. The language is used to evaluate expressions and conditions. Right now the evaluation is mixed with the parsing.

I'm trying to optimize it and the bottleneck is lexer and the parser. So I decided to parse it before hand and only evaluate on runtime.

The question is that which one is faster or cleaner, generate JS code before and only run that or generate AST and iterate on it on runtime?

Comment: `eval` = invoking the compiler = expensive.

Comment: It looks like you're in essence wondering whether compiled or interpreted code is faster. Compiled code is almost always going to be faster, but it can cause more headaches than interpreted.

Comment: @JanDvorak Well one thing is that this all happens one nodejs, so I have plenty of startup time. I call `eval` before to parse it on startup and then I run the resulting function on runtime.

Comment: @Bubbles I'm trying to both save headaches and CPU cycles. But note that I'm generating javascript, it's not machine code.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about any delays that only happen once on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general*, faster will always be to generate anything that is closest to machine code. In your case generating javascript would be faster.

The generated javascript code would be executed directly by the underlying C/C++ interpreter (and in some cases compiled JIT into machine code). In contrast, writing your own VM in javascript to execute the AST would run on an additional layer of VM - javascript.

**note: There are some corner cases where interpreters can sometimes execute as fast as native code. Forth being an example because it's interpreter is dead simple - it's just a table of function pointers.*

Comment: If your compile times are long, an interpreter can be faster even if coded in a naive way.  The tradeoff is simple:  "compiletime+executetime(compiledprogram)" vs.  "interprettime".  Pick the one that wins most often in your circumstances, if you have the energy to build a compiler.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Compile time happens once. So even if it's longer it's a win. Besides, regardless if it's interpreted or not it is compiled in this case (the OP mentioned that he's compiling to AST). The hard part is getting the AST. Generating instructions from an AST is trivial (in fact, it is fast enough that you can usually interpret the AST directly without generating any executable output).